# How can get another data of table using session by email id in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

My table name- persons 
my table columns

```
    fname lname email password
```

I want to get fname from table using session by email id or password. I want to display fname on another page after login. please help me .

```
session_start();

$cser = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "srptech") or die("connection failed:" . mysqli_error());

if (isset($_REQUEST['login'])) {
    $c = $_REQUEST['fname'];
    $a = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $b = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $res = mysqli_query($cser, "select fname from persons where email='$a'and password='$b'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $fname = $row['fname'];

        $_SESSION["user-name"] = $fname;

    }

    $result = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if ($result == true) {
        $_SESSION["login"] = "1";

        $_SESSION["email-id"] = $a;

        header("location:my-account.php");
        exit();
        session_write_close();
    } else {
        header("location:index.php?err=1");
    }

}
```

And another page - my-account.php

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["login"])) // $_SESSION is a variable and login is a SESSION name
{
    header("location:index.php");
} else {
    echo 'Welcome' . '<h3>' . $_SESSION["email-id"] . '</h3>';
    echo 'Welcome' . '<h3>' . $_SESSION["user-name"] . '</h3>';

}
```

Email is echo on another page but fname is not displayed (echo)

`Error- Invalid user-name.`

How can echo fname on another page? Please help me.

Comment: OUCH! This means you are using PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS!!! PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: I would also suggest Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: And Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: _more sidenotes:_ `header("location:index.php");` will not work, because you have output here: `?>
<?php`

Comment: i want get fname from my table and set it to session and echo on another page . Please help me using my code .

Comment: Kindly solve my problem using my code

Comment: where does `Error- Invalid user-name.` come from ? there is no such echo in your code

Comment: see the echo in my code     `echo 'Welcome'.'<h3>'.$_SESSION["user-name"].'</h3>';`

Comment: did you check the logs for error(s) ?

Comment: I have check all thinks related it . Email echo on another page perfect but user-name is invalid. Kindly review my code and remove my mistake and solve it and post in answer. Make this code working

Comment: Formatted the PHP code to be readable.

Answer (score -1):

I updated your script, now it's safe to use no SQL injection possible

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['login']))
    {
        $Email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $Password = $_REQUEST['password'];

        $DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "srptech");

        if ($DB->connect_errno)
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $DB->connect_error);
            exit();
        }

        $STMT = $DB->prepare("SELECT `fname` FROM `persons` WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ? LIMIT 1");
        $STMT->bind_param("ss", $Email, $Password);
        $STMT->execute();
        $STMT->bind_result($FirstName);
        $STMT->fetch();
        $STMT->close();

        if ($FirstName)
        {
            session_start();

            $_SESSION["user-name"] = $FirstName;
            $_SESSION["login"] = "1";
            $_SESSION["email-id"] = $Email;

            header("location:my-account.php");
            exit();
        }

         header("location:index.php?err=1");
    }
?>
```

Comment: _"Try this"_ answers without any explanation _why_ this could solve the problem rarely compete with the best answers. Please include what you have changed and why!

Comment: _sidenote_: a `;` is missing

Comment: Mr @Ali Khazaee there is an error in your code - error is -------`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\loginprocess.php on line 19`

Comment: @ShaktiRana, Try it again